# GitHub pull request template: get current branch name

Tags: templates, github, branch, git-branch, pull-request

I'm creating a pull request template for my repository.

I added a new file, following the instructions at https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request-template-for-your-repository/ , and now I want its' body to contain a string generated using the current branch name (the pull request branch name).

Couldn't find the answer in GitHub's docs, would like to know if it's possible and if so how?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I tweeted the question: "is there a way to get the current branch name in a pull request template?"

mentioning the GitHub account and this is the answer I was given:

> No, there currently isn't but if this is something you want included in all pull request submissions, you might want to check out Probot: https://probot.github.io . I recently created https://github.com/probot/view-rendered … that edits the pull request body to add rendered links for docs.

Link to tweet: https://twitter.com/korndaniel1/status/1022468460226469888

Answer (score 6):

Another way to achieve that would be to change the template file in a pre-commit hook.

```bash
#!/bin/sh
​
# Create git pull request template based on current branch
​
# Get current branch
branch=$(git branch --show-current)
​
# Check if template already contains current branch name
if grep -q $branch ./.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md; then
    exit 0
fi
​
echo creating new pr template 
​
# Write text to the pr template file
cat > ./.github/PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE.md <<- EOM
##  Ticket Reference:
​
${branch}
EOM
```

Comment: I always love when there's an answer that says, "This is impossible" but then there's an answer like this one that says, "Here's how to do it." It just demonstrates how good you are.

Comment: @lilHar Just tried this, doesn't actually work. GitHub uses the pull request template from `main`.

Comment: @NilsGuillermin Do you mean "main" as in the folder, or "main" as in the branch?

Comment: @lilHar definitely main as in branch, could also be called "master" if you have an older project

Comment: @NilsGuillermin are you still having the problem because it surely worked for me.

Comment: @nico_dkd one doubt. if you change the PULL_REQUEST_TEMPLATE  file in pre-commit hook then this file need to be push in each pull request right ? Also when you are raising a pull request at that time this changes file is not there in repo yet and github will pick the content from the file that is there in the current repo. let me know if i am missing anything here.